# Redirecting stderr using exec

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to redirect all commands error output to a file like that:

```
exec 2>errlog.txt
```

but executing the line above leaves me with a "frozen" terminal - the terminal doesn't respond to my input at all. What's more interesting redirecting stdout using `exec` works great. What's wrong with error redirection?

Comment: If you're using bash, it does respond to your commands -- it just isn't echoing them back (just as the prompt). Try blindly typing `pwd<Enter>` or `ls<Enter>`.

Comment: You may find this discussion helpful: [Why does bash interactive shell by default write its prompt and echoes its interactive input to stderr?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/381081/65304)

Answer (score 5):

```
exec 2>errlog.txt
```

If you're using `bash` (and not `ksh93` or `dash` [1]), that will **not** freeze your terminal. That will only prevent the shells's prompts and the characters you enter from being echoed back.

But you will able to retrieve them later from `errlog.txt` ;-) You can easily check that by blindly typing `pwd<Enter>` or `ls<Enter>`: the commands will work fine and display their output. Also, ^C and ^Z will work as expected.

There are two things at work here:

1) `bash` is always printing its prompt to stderr, not to the controlling terminal.

2) the readline library bash is using to implement command line editing will turn off the echo flag on the terminal [2], and print itself the characters entered by the user to stderr.

If you start a bash shell with `bash --noediting` (which will cause it to not use the readline library), the characters you enter will be echoed back by the tty driver, and only the prompts will go to the redirected stderr.

A workaround for this may be to use `tee` and a process substitution:

```
exec 2> >(trap '' INT; tee errlog.txt >/dev/tty)
```

[1] see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/475396/308316) for an explanation why some shells will badly misfunction if you do that, and why that will work as expected in `zsh`.

[2] see the `c_lflag` / `ECHO` in the `termios(3)` manpage and `stty echo` in `stty(1)` for a description.