# C language programs not workning on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, process, c, visual-studio-code

I wrote a simple code to find even and odd numbers in c.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
   int num;
   printf("Enter an integer: ");
   scanf(" %d", &num);

   (num % 2 == 0) ? printf("%d is even.", num) : printf("%d is odd.", num);
   return 0;
}
```

The code starts running without stopping and gives message like this

```
[Running] cd "/home/atharva/Projects/c c++/" && gcc Even_odd.c -o Even_odd && "/home/atharva/Projects/c c++/"Even_odd
```

I am using ubuntu.What should be done?

Comment: That command is just the build-and-run process. So it gets run. I think it is waiting for you to enter an integer. It probably does not prompt because it is buffered: try adding a `\n` at the end of the printf string.

Comment: No, the output dosen't even show printf statement and nor is asking for the integer

Comment: I didn't say it is asking for the integer. It didn't ask, but it is (probably) *waiting* for input. Just type `5` and see what happens ! If not, just put `printf ("Hello, World.\n"); return (0);` as the first line under `main`. If it can't even do that right, your IDE is broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program is running, but you won't see any output from your program because the output is buffered.

The output is buffered because the string that you have outputted with `printf()` is not delimited by a newline at the end.  The standard library will buffer the output until a newline is outputted or until you explicitly call `fflush()` on the output stream.  This buffering is done for efficiency.

One solution is to either output the string with a newline at the end:

```
printf("Enter an integer:\n");
```

... or to explicitly call `fflush()`:

```
printf("Enter an integer: ");
fflush(stdout);
```

However, the *correct* way of doing it is to output any text intended for user interaction on the standard error stream, like most other Unix utilities do:

```
fprintf(stderr, "Enter an integer: ");
```

The standard error stream is unbuffered by default.

The other `printf()` statements in the code suffers from the same issue and should probably have newlines appended to the strings they output (as they output the result, not user interaction messages).

See also:

- [Why does bash interactive shell by default write its prompt and echoes its interactive input to stderr?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/380012)
- [When to use standard error stream in command-line application?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/336983)

Comment: now it is executing till printf but now the problem is  I am unable to type integer in inout

Comment: @ATHARVASHETTY I'm assuming that you are able to but that you don't see the output.  This is due to the buffering again. You have multiple `printf()` statements with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your example works for me at the command line.

Copy your code to `Even_odd.c` and then

```
make Even_odd    # A quicker alternative to "gcc Even_odd.c -o Even_odd"
./Even_odd
Enter an integer:
```

If you're not really running from the command line you might need `fflush(stdout)` between the `printf` and the `sscanf`. This is because *stdout* is line buffered and the line may not get flushed (written) to the terminal before the input is requested by `sscanf`.

Don't forget `\n` at the end of your result strings, for example, `printf("%d is even.\n", num)`

Comment: If I add fflush(stdout) in the code, it executes till printf statement but i am unable to enter an integer. It is not identifying any keystrokes.

Comment: Nothing I know of outputs that `[Running]` message -- certainly not a shell. What IDE (development environment) are you using? Maybe it is launching the code in the background (which would prevent it reading from the terminal).

Comment: @Paul_Pedant my thought too, although perhaps "_If you're not really running from the command line_" is too subtle..?

Comment: @roaima  Obviously too subtle, especially for me ;-)  Personally, I would check stdin is a terminal before I start putting up prompts, and also fprintf/fflush to stdin for prompts. But I would expect stdio to flush all buffers on exit regardless.

Comment: It does flush on edit, but an output without a newline messes up the prompt

Comment: Maybe visual studio code has an option to run the program with its descriptors connected to a tty.